# How to Get Group count in AgGrid

Tags: ag-grid

I have set `rowgroup:true` for one of the column in `Aggrid`.

I want to display number of groups it created and display it in the footer. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ag-grid API does not provide any methods that can allow you to calculate the number of row groups within your group. However, this can be easily counted using Vanilla JavaScript, with the use of JavaScript's [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). First, we get the row nodes data from the grid itself, then we construct a Set that consists of that specific property (in this example, we assume that the row group property is 'country'). Since we can only add unique values to a Set, we can be sure that the size of the Set is the row group count.

```
countCountries() {
  const rowData = [];
  const countrySet = new Set();
  this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
  rowData.map(obj => {
    if (obj) {
      countrySet.add(obj.country);
    }
  });
  console.log(countrySet.size);
  return countrySet.size;
}
```

Then, we can simply add the count to the footer by implementing [pinned rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/). You will have to specify the input property binding for `pinnedBottomRowData`, as well as the event binding for `firstDataRendered`, such that the country count will be calculated only after the data is rendered.

```
 <ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 420px;"
  id="myGrid"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [animateRows]="true"
  [enableRangeSelection]="true"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [pinnedBottomRowData]="pinnedBottomRowData"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
 ></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts itself,

```
onFirstDataRendered(event) {
  this.pinnedBottomRowData = this.createData();
}

createData() {
  const result = [];
  result.push({
    country:`count:${this.countCountries()}`,
  });
  return result;
}
```

I have created a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6e8heqcYNmDTC1VZfm2p?p=preview) for your reference. This should nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you for the answer, is there any javascript version of code instead of angular/.

Comment: @Sunilkumar Oh, I am sorry, I assumed you are following a framework such as Angular. The methods such as `countCountries` are pure vanilla JavaScript. It should work. May I know which part of my code are you referring to?

Comment: ok..i used json loop and filter using set() to get group count.. and update footer using jquery...